# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar "subscript out of bounds"?

Tags: r, rstudio, matrices

Quiero ejemplificar mi problema con la siguiente matriz.

```
   my_mat <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 5)    # Crear matriz 
my_mat                              # Print
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    5    9   13   17
# [2,]    2    6   10   14   18
# [3,]    3    7   11   15   19
# [4,]    4    8   12   16   20
```

Entiendo que si pido la fila 3, no tendré este error ("subscript out of bounds")

```
my_mat[3, ]                         # Imprimir fila 3 
# [1]  3  7 11 15 19
```

Pero si pido que me devuelva la fila 10 la cual no existe en esta matriz, es cuando me da este error:

```
my_mat[10, ]                        # Intentar pedir la fila 10
# Error in my_mat[10, ] : subscript out of bounds
```

Sabiendo que es imposible pedir esta fila ya que no esta definida en mi matriz original, existe alguna funcion que me indique que esta fila es nula y o tener alguna referencia de esta fila, es evidente que no existe, pero me gustaria poder trabajar este error para posteriormente integrarlas en un if y omitir todas las matrices cuyos elementos no existen en esa matriz.

Si no soy muy claro, no dudes en preguntarme mas.

Comment: ¡Hola @Pablo Garcia! Entendiendo qué es lo que quieres hacer después, quizás podamos ayudarte mejor. En cualquier caso podrías hacer una comprobación de si el índice excede el número de filas o columnas y de ser así que imprima por pantalla un mensaje

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos estrategias para encarar tu problema, pedir permiso o pedir perdón, que básicamente significa: verificamos las dimensiones antes o capturamos el eventual error.

##### 1. Pedir permiso

No hay más que validar las dimensiones de la matriz, y verificar que cumpla con los valores esperados:

```
fila <- 10
if (fila > dim(my_mat)[1]) {
  stop("El número de fila no es consistente con el tamaño de la matriz")
} else {
  my_mat[fila, ]
}
```

Nota: en caso en que la fila solicitada sea superior al tamaño de la matriz, en este ejemplo directamente detenemos la ejecución con un `stop()` pero obviamente lo que se haga en este caso dependerá de lo que estás buscando.

##### 2. Pedir perdón

```
fila <- 10
tryCatch(
  expr = {
    # Código a evaluar
    my_mat[fila, ]
  },
  error = function(e) {
    # En caso de error hacemos esto:
    print(paste("El error capturado fue", e))
  }
)
```

En este caso actuamos a partir del error, el `tryCatch()` evalúa cierto código definido en el parámetro `expr` y en el caso que se dispare un error, se captura y eventualmente hacemos algo con él, definiendo una función para el manejo de éste.

Puede aplicar cualquiera de los dos criterio, por ejemplo si no quieres el error y en caso que que fila recibida no sea válida, retornar por ejemplo una fila de valores `NA`:

```
fila <- 10

dato <- tryCatch(my_mat[fila, ], error = function(e) {my_mat[1,] * NA})

if (fila > dim(my_mat)[1]) dato = my_mat[1,] * NA else dato = my_mat[fila, ]
```